# How to suspend and resume a thread user input through the command prompt?

Tags: java

How to suspend and resume a thread user input through the command prompt?

I want a program where user can get the thread running from the stage where he stooped the thread by suspending.

package foo;

import java.util.Vector;

public class ThreadTest {

```
private Vector<String> threadNames = new Vector<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();

    test.threadTest(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

    System.out.println(test.threadNames);

}

private void threadTest(int numOfThreads) {

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numOfThreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

        threads[i] = new foo.ThreadTest.MyThread();

        threads[i].start();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

        try {

            threads[i].join();

        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}

    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

            i = i + 0;

        }

        threadNames.add(getName());

    }

}
```

}

Comment: It would also help if you could further explain what you're looking to do.  (I hope you're not trying to serialize a thread...)  Are you just looking to pause/resume execution of a part of your code?

Comment: What code have you got so far, what have you tried?

Comment: i edited my question and pasted the code i have tried..
i have no idea how to suspend or resume a thread by user input in console :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options.  All will require some sort of [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).  The best approach will likely be based on [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions).

In particular, take a look at everything that is available on the [`ThreadMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) (JMX).  Now, this doesn't provide you the exact functions it sounds like you're looking for, but you could write your own that provides the extended functions you need.

Also, JMX is typically accessed through something like jconsole - which is GUI based.  However, JMX is just an API, and you could write your own console-based client that exposes the functionality you require through CLI.

See also: [calling java methods from a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864948/calling-java-methods-from-a-terminal/8864986)

Comment: can i get some codes?
im new to java..
it will be helpfull for me

Comment: I can't spend the time here to provide you a complete solution, but the details I provided should help give you enough information to either properly A) search for an existing solution, or B) find the proper resources to learn and write your own.  Otherwise, hopefully someone else will provide you with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle this fairly simply with two threads?

- Thread One would be responsible for listening to user input.  On certain user inputs it would suspend or resume Thread Two
- Thread Two would be responsible for any task which your want to be able to
  suspend and resume.

You also may want to take a look at the [Java Concurrency Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: actually im getting programs for suspending or resume but not bu user input control